# Django Pythonanywhere, model field default=timezone.now() repeats the same time multiple times

Tags: python, sql, django, web, pythonanywhere

I am hosting a web app on pythonanywhere.

In one of my models I have this field, capturing the **datetime** when the user performs a certain action (submits a form in this case), which subsequently gets recorded in the database.

```
from django.utils import timezone
upload_datetime = models.DateTimeField('date uploaded', default=timezone.now())
```

However, seen in the image below, most of the rows in the database display the exact same time. This should under normal circumstances be a very rare case, so I am assuming a bug here. Can I get any help on where to start looking?

[Database entries of upload_datetime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK0sN.png)

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are generally not acceptable: your question must be self -contained.  You should also provide evidence that the upload times are other than what you get from `DateTimeField`; can you validate this from your OS functions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `now` function, *not* call the function, since then the function will be called once when the class in interpreted, and then reuse the same `datetime` each time.

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload_datetime = models.DateTimeField('date uploaded', default=now)
```

so *without* parenthesis.

But you actually do not need to set a default yourself. Django has an [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) to specify that you want to initialize it with the current timestamp:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload_datetime = models.DateTimeField('date uploaded', auto_now_add=True)
```